# Carregar conteúdo da página sem dar refresh na página

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde/noite a todos.
Senhores, possuo o seguinte layout: (ex.png)

[image: ex.png]

Como podem ver, estou criando uma área administrativa para meu sistema, onde a barra superior e a lateral( ambas em preto) são fixas, e toda a parte branca da pagina será de conteúdo. O que eu quero é, que ao clicar em qualquer opção(ou quase todas) que alterasse apenas o conteúdo (parte branca) sem eu ter que criar uma outra página com as mesmas barras superior e lateral.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar ajax, ou até mesmo AngularJS para essa tarefa.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-target="home.html">Home</li>
  <li data-target="cadastro.html">Cadastro</li>
  <li data-target="listar.html">Listar</li>
</ul>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
$('#conteudo').load( this.data("target") );
})
```

Veja em funcionamento: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjxnk4L2/8/)

dê uma olhada: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: No caso, vou criar uma div lá que vai receber o conteúdo e quando for carregar, seto a div que eu quero, entendi certo?

Comment: Sim, crie vários arquivos ( cada arquivo será o conteúdo a ser carregado ) e na chamada ( click do menu ) chame o arquivo com a div.

Comment: @MatheusRagoso , muito obrigado. Segui sua dica e aprimorei um pouco e resolvi. Muito obrigado! :)